# UDK Remote : what kind of data sent while dragging an image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, unreal-development-kit

I'm using UDK Remote.While tapping, it send 56 bytes of data. What data are sent during dragging?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, mind clarifying that a bit?

Comment: i want to implement an application like UDK Remote. While tapping the screen, the UDK send some data to the client. I think the positions tapped by the user are sent to client. I want to know exactly what data are sent during tapping.

Answer (score 0):

The touch positions (x,y coordinates) on the touch screen. What else could it be?